# How can I use slugs in Django url like mysite.com/user

Tags: python, django

I want to create a directory like `website.com/user` after the user get logged in!

And I'm not sure which `url pattern` in my app/urls.py should call this `myfun` to capture slug: `user` in url

```
def myfun(request, user):
    user = TwitterUser().objects.get(user=user)
    return render(request, 'authorization/home.html', {'user' : user})
```

**models.py**

```
class TwitterUser(models.Model):
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    user = models.SlugField('auth.User', unique=True, null=True)
```

**app/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('twitter_login/', views.twitter_login, name='twitter_login'),
    path('twitter_callback/', views.twitter_callback, name='twitter_callback'),
    path('twitter_logout/', views.twitter_logout, name='twitter_logout'),
]
```

**view.py**

```
def twitter_login(request):
    twitter_api = TwitterAPI()
    url, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = twitter_api.twitter_login()
    if url is None or url == '':
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unable to login. Please try again.')
        return render(request, 'authorization/error_page.html')
    else:
        twitter_auth_token = TwitterAuthToken.objects.filter(oauth_token=oauth_token).first()
        if twitter_auth_token is None:
            twitter_auth_token = TwitterAuthToken(oauth_token=oauth_token, oauth_token_secret=oauth_token_secret)
            twitter_auth_token.save()
        else:
            twitter_auth_token.oauth_token_secret = oauth_token_secret
            twitter_auth_token.save()
        return redirect(url)


def twitter_callback(request):
    if 'denied' in request.GET:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unable to login or login canceled. Please try again.')
        return render(request, 'authorization/error_page.html')
    twitter_api = TwitterAPI()
    oauth_verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
    oauth_token = request.GET.get('oauth_token')
    twitter_auth_token = TwitterAuthToken.objects.filter(oauth_token=oauth_token).first()
    if twitter_auth_token is not None:
        access_token, access_token_secret = twitter_api.twitter_callback(oauth_verifier, oauth_token, twitter_auth_token.oauth_token_secret)
        if access_token is not None and access_token_secret is not None:
            twitter_auth_token.oauth_token = access_token
            twitter_auth_token.oauth_token_secret = access_token_secret
            twitter_auth_token.save()
            # Create user
            info = twitter_api.get_me(access_token, access_token_secret)
            if info is not None:
                twitter_user_new = TwitterUser(twitter_id=info[0]['id'], screen_name=info[0]['username'],
                                               name=info[0]['name'], profile_image_url=info[0]['profile_image_url'])
                twitter_user_new.twitter_oauth_token = twitter_auth_token
                user, twitter_user = create_update_user_from_twitter(twitter_user_new)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('index')
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unable to get profile details. Please try again.')
                return render(request, 'authorization/error_page.html')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unable to get access token. Please try again.')
            return render(request, 'authorization/error_page.html')
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Unable to retrieve access token. Please try again.')
        return render(request, 'authorization/error_page.html')


@login_required
@twitter_login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'authorization/home.html')


@login_required
def twitter_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('index')
```

Your response will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your **urls.py** with the relevant placeholder and get the placeholder as parameter in the view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<str:user>', views.myfun, name='myfun')
]
```

You can see more info here in Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Nope not working! Are you sure?

Comment: @OVO30, yes. can you describe what exactly is not working?

Comment: The above code which I have given is exact same as in my project. So, can you write exact same code to capture the slug in url?

Comment: @OVO30, this is what I gave in the answer. Just add `path('<str:user>', views.myfun, name='myfun')` to your `urlpatterns`

Comment: Yes! but getting ERROR saying:

AttributeError at /authorization/twitter_callback/

'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: I think something is wrong with my : def myfun?